# For-loops, array and ++ operator

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, increment

Beginner asking a question.

I am testing the increment ++ operator within for-loop and the outcome is different than I expect it to be and I have no clue why. The code is not for a specific program.

```
        int[] numbers = new int[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = i++;
        }

        for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("value is {0} at position {1}", numbers[a], a);
        }
```

Output is:

```
value is 0 at position 0
value is 0 at position 1
value is 2 at position 2
value is 0 at position 3
value is 4 at position 4
value is 0 at position 5
value is 6 at position 6
value is 0 at position 7
value is 8 at position 8
value is 0 at position 9
```

If i run the first for-loop without the ++ increment (numbers[i] = i;), the values are consecutive and in order (0, 1, 2, 3 etc.). Why the ++ increment causes every other value to be zero? I thought it would be something like 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 etc.

If I run numbers[i] = i+1;
outcome is something I would expect:

```
value is 1 at position 0
value is 2 at position 1
value is 3 at position 2
value is 4 at position 3
value is 5 at position 4
value is 6 at position 5
value is 7 at position 6
value is 8 at position 7
value is 9 at position 8
value is 10 at position 9
```

Comment: Because of the double increment of `i`, you never set a value to index 1,3,5,7 and 9.

Comment: You are changing the value of `i` inside you loop. That's strange. You index is modified. `i++` means `i = i + 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you write is

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    numbers[i] = i++;
}
```

that is equal to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    numbers1[i] = i;
    i = i + 1;
}
```

First time `i` is start from 0

```
// I change the i to real value for easy understanding
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    numbers1[0] = 0;
    i = 0 + 1;
    //so here i is 1
}
```

Second time `i` is 2, because after first time loop the `i` is 1 then the `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)` will increase `i` from 1 to 2,
so the second time loop will be

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    numbers1[2] = 2;
    i = 2 + 1;
    //so here i is 3
}
```

So now you know the `numbers[0]` is 0 and `numbers[2]` is 2 but about the `numbers[1]` you don't set the value for it so it will be the default value which the default value of `int` is 0.

Answer (score -2):

Thank you Michael! I verified that out also by myself when messing around with the code. First I tried adding one more `i++`;

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
  numbers[i] = i++;
  i++;
}
```

It gave me value on every third row.

And then third `i++`:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
  numbers[i] = i++;
  i++;
  i++;
}
```

Now value every fourth line.

Solved.